# Broken bolt in intake

Tags: engine, gmc, canyon

I have a "2005" Canyon with a 3.5 I5,the other day I was putting the intake back on and broke a bolt in the intake,I think I have access to the broken bolt thru my wheel well. i have a good idea on how to get it out without removing the rest of the intake. The question I have is that the broken bolt is still in the manifold, they don't fall out. Does anyone know how the bolts are held in the intake, are they just held in by a rubber grommet or something? Can I pull real hard to get the remainder of the bolt out without breaking my intake bolt flange? When I had it out I didn't pay any attention to what was holding them in the intake. The intake don't seem to be sucking air, but I am afraid to take it on the X-way,don't want to get it started sucking.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are usually held by grommets in the intake. They should not be over tightened, torque to 89 inch pounds (7.5 ft lbs)

If the bolt broke, part of it is still in the cylinder head and needs removed, best option is just remove the intake again and remove the broken bolt from the cylinder head